Wordpress stores an array with an additional level
I am learning to develop plugins for Wordpress and I am facing a problem.
In the backend I have a form to add Custom Post Types to my test plugin.
This is the code which I use to retrieve and manipulate the user's input
public function cptSanitize( $input ) {  

    $output = array();
    
    var_dump($input);
    $output[$input['post_type']] = $input;
    var_dump($output); 
    var_dump(serialize($output)); die();
    return $output;
}

The outputs for the 3 var_dump() are in order as follows
array(5) { 
    ["post_type"]=> string(11) "comic-books" 
    ["singular_name"]=> string(10) "Comic book" 
    ["plural_name"]=> string(11) "Comic books" 
    ["public"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["has_archive"]=> string(1) "1" 
}

array(1) { 
    ["comic-books"]=> array(5) { 
        ["post_type"]=> string(11) "comic-books" 
        ["singular_name"]=> string(10) "Comic book" 
        ["plural_name"]=> string(11) "Comic books" 
        ["public"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["has_archive"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
}

"a:1:{
    s:11:"comic-books";
    a:5:{
        s:9:"post_type";s:11:"comic-books";
        s:13:"singular_name";s:10:"Comic book";
        s:11:"plural_name";s:11:"Comic books";
        s:6:"public";s:1:"1";
        s:11:"has_archive";s:1:"1";
    }
}"

The problem is that if I remove the die(); as well as the var_dump()s and let WP store the values into the database, they are stored with an additional level with an empty key compared to the PHP serialization
a:1:{
    s:0:"";
    a:1:{
        s:11:"comic-books";
        a:5:{
            s:9:"post_type";s:11:"comic-books";
            s:13:"singular_name";s:10:"Comic book";
            s:11:"plural_name";s:11:"Comic books";
            s:6:"public";s:1:"1";
            s:11:"has_archive";s:1:"1";
        }
    }
}

Why does that happen? I want to have the data stored as PHP serializes the array, not with an additional level. How should I do?
The reason I am using that structure is that I want to store multiple arrays which have the post_type value as key and the full array as value.
Eidt: What I have noticed is that this problem only occurs when the option doesn't yet exist into the wp_options table. If an entry for this option exists, even an empty array a:0:{}, the code above works correctly and stores the data as I expected, but why that happens?

To be clear, are you using update_option? Also, are you manually calling serialize, or are you doing that just for debugging? Assuming yes to the first question, are you then calling get_option, and is the result not what you want? Basically, is the issue only when you inspect it in the database?

I do not call serialize that was just for debugging purpose and see how PHP would serialize the variable I want to store into the DB. I delegate all the process of storing to WP. Into the form's action I've put options.php and as far as I've understood from the tutorial I am following it should take care of the insert/update, so I am not calling update_option myself.
get_option returns an array with the additional level with empty key as stored into the DB.
